# Swift : Single Selection with UITableViews

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a regular UITableView with single selection enabled. My problem is that if the user selects multiple rows then the original rows remain selected. I also have a problem where the highlight remains gray no matter if I set the cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue

My view controller is defined in the Storyboard.

Table View

- Content: Dynamic Prototypes
- Selection: Single Selection
- Show Selection on Touch [X]
- Background: Black Color
- Index Row Limit: 0

Table Cell View

- Style: Custom
- Selection: Blue
- Background: Black Color

Here are some screenshots:

[image: selection 1] [image: selection 2]

Here is my code:

```
class AreaViewController: UITableViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColour
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("areacell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Blue

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell Contents"
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return cell
    }

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
    {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("areacell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    }
}
```

I must be missing something obvious but I've not been able to see anything non standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh! I found it at last. Seems like I was calling let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("areacell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Removing it caused everything to start working again. Obvious really. Thanks for your help zisoft in putting me on the right road.

Answer (score 1):

From the [UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle)

> UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue The cell has a default background
>   color when selected.
>
> In iOS 7, the selection color is no longer blue. Use
>   UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault instead.

If you want a special background color for selected cells you have to set the cells' `backgroundView`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView

    return cell
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you zisoft. I had tried this code before and it only sort of works. The highlight is red but only when the row is being 'touched' as soon as you remove your finger it greys out as my original post.

Comment: I cannot reproce this, it works as it should. Do you call `deselectRowAtIndexPath()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Or did you use `deselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` by accident? Same happend to me some while ago, due to code completion. The difference was hard to see :-)

Comment: No I have checked my code and I never call deselectRowAtIndexPath in the entire project. Now that someone has sanity checked me I'm going to try and recreate the view from scratch. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks.